# Error in official Twain header VS2012 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, twain

I am trying to program a C++ Wrapper for TWAIN with Visual Studio 2012, Windows 7.
I have installed Twain SDK and have all DLL like Twain_32.dll in C:/Windows
I have twain.h : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/ooo/trunk/main/twain/inc/twain.h

And I have my main :

```
   #include <windows.h>
   #include "twain.h"

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

And I get 200 errors like for this line

```
#ifdef  _MSWIN_
typedef HANDLE TW_HANDLE; 
typedef LPVOID TW_MEMREF;

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'TW_HANDLE'
```

How can I resolve that ?

Comment: In which files/lines do you get these errors? The small example you provided compiles with no errors.

Comment: at the begining of  twain.h :(

#ifdef  _MSWIN_
    typedef HANDLE TW_HANDLE; 
    typedef LPVOID TW_MEMREF;

Comment: Please edit your post and put the information in your question.  People shouldn't have to search the comments for more information about your problem.

Comment: I meant which source files. It appears `HANDLE` is undefined by that line, are you always including `windows.h` before `twain.h`?

Comment: I have only 2 files : twain.h and main.cpp. The errors is caught in twain.h which I get from official Twain Project.

Comment: The source lines you included in your question do not exist as posted in the file you linked to. In fact `_MSWIN_` doesn't appear anywhere in the header file you linked to. Post the actual code and include line numbers.